# Array position comparison in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 arrays, each has 2 elements.

For example: The arrays are `array['M','UM']` and `'{0,1}'`.

I want to do the following:

```
update table set value=0 where code='M';
update table set value=1 where code='UM';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it. The idea is something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_translate(varchar[], int[])
NULL
AS
$$
DECLARE
   arrStr ALIAS FOR $1;
   arrInt ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
   FOR I IN array_lower(arrStr, 1)..array_upper(arrStr, 1) LOOP
    update table set value=arrInt[I] where code=arrStr[I];
   END LOOP;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
   STABLE 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```